# Angularfire2 how to handle multiple Observables in angular4-5

Tags: angular, observable, angularfire2

What is the best way to get the data from multiple observables before executing a function

EXAMPLE:

provider.ts

```
obs1 = this.afDB.object(`app/radio`).snapshotChanges();
obs2 = this.afDB.object(`app/users`).snapshotChanges();
obs3 = this.afDB.object(`app/song`).snapshotChanges();
```

app.ts

```
doSomething(){

console.log('this is my', ${radio}, 'it plays on this date:' ,${date}, 'this song', ${song}`);

}
```

i place the subscribtions inside eachother.. it works but..  what is the right way of handling this async behaviour?

```
doSomething(){

provider.obs1.subscribe(val1 =>{
provider.obs2.subscribe(val2 =>{
provider.obs3.subscribe(val3 =>{

 console.log('this is my', ${val1.payload.val().radio}, 'it plays on this date:' ,${val2.payload.val().date}, 'this song', ${val3.payload.val().song}`);

});
});
});

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **forkJoin** operator.

```
doSomething(){
   Observable.forkJoin(
      provider.obs1,
      provider.obs2,
      provider.obs3
   ).subscribe(data => {
       console.log("values: ",data[0], data[1], data[2]) 
   }, err => {
       console.log("Handle error here");
   })
}
```